# JavaScript/jQuery rock, paper, or scissors game with pictures

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, loops

So, im trying to create a rock paper scissors game using some javascript and jQuery code.

I'm trying to follow some rules on how the game should play out:

1. Create a loop that gives the user 3 picks against the computer's pick. Each time, you will prompt for the user to select “rock”, “paper”, or “scissors” (not by typing out the word, but by "selecting" the image).
2. The computer will then randomly choose rock, paper, or scissors. Highlight the picture of rock, paper, or scissors for your choice, as well as show a separate image that shows the computer’s choice of rock, paper, or scissors.

In the end of the 3 rounds i would like to display a score board of how many ties, wins, and loses for the user.

Here's my code so far. So far i have tried making the user click on either rock paper, or scissors and then compare it to the randomly generated outcome from the computer. My problem right now is that there is no alerts popping up on my screen. This tells me that my if statements for comparing each choice isn't working properly.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript">
$(function() {

for (i=0; i < 3; i++)
{


    var computerChoice = null;
    var userChoice = null;



    $('#rock').click(function(){
        userChoice = "rock";
    });
    $('#paper').click(function(){
        userChoice = "paper";
    });
    $('#scissors').click(function(){
        userChoice = "scissors";
    });


    function newComputerChoice ()
    {
        computerChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
        //take the random number from computerChoice above and assign it rock paper or scissors.
        if (computerChoice == 1)
            {
                computerChoice = "rock";
            }
        else if (computerChoice == 2)
            {
                computerChoice = "paper";
            }
        else 
            {
                computerChoice = "scissors";
            }

    }

    if (userChoice == computerChoice){
        alert ("Tie!");
    } else if (userChoice == "rock" && computerChoice == "scissors"){
        alert ("You win!");
    } else if (userChoice == "paper" && computerChoice == "rock"){
        alert ("You win!");
    } else if (userChoice == "scissors" && computerChoice == "paper"){
        alert ("You win!");
    } else if (computerChoice == "rock" && userChoice == "scissors"){
        alert ("Sorry, you lose.")
    } else if (computerChoice == "paper" && userChoice == "rock"){
        alert ("Sorry, you lose.")
    } else if (computerChoice == "scissors" && userChoice == "paper"){
        alert ("Sorry, you lose.")
    }


}  

}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Make your choice:</h1>

<img src="rock.jpg" name="rock" id = "rock"/>
<img src="paper.jpg" name="paper" id = "paper"/>
<img src="scissors.jpg" name="scissors" id = "scissors"/>

<h1>Computer Chose:</h1>



</body>
</html>
```

Lastly, i need to display the computer choice with the same images, but i'm not sure how to only display one at a time depending on what was randomly chosen.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: My problem right now is that there is no alerts popping up on my screen. This tells me that my if statements for comparing each choice isn't working properly.

Comment: You never call the `newComputerChoice()` function.

Comment: First, extract your click events outside of the for loop. Second extract the `newComputerChoice` function out of your for loop. You are ultimatly adding a NEW click event and creating a NEW function every time the user selects a choice. This is not what you want.

Comment: You don't understand event-driven programming, which is essential for programming Javascript browser apps.

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop. The click handlers should run the code that gets the computer's choice, then compares which button the user clicked on with that. They should keep a counter, and stop when the counter reaches 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, it should be fullfill your need.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Make your choice:</h1>

    <img src="rock.jpg" name="rock" id = "rock"/>
    <img src="paper.jpg" name="paper" id = "paper"/>
    <img src="scissors.jpg" name="scissors" id = "scissors"/>

    <h1>Computer Chose:</h1>
    <script language=javascript>
        var userChoice = null;
        var computerChoice = null;
        $(document).ready(
            function ()
            {
                 $('#rock').click(function(){
                    userChoice = "rock";
                    newComputerChoice();
                    computResult();
                });
                $('#paper').click(function(){
                    userChoice = "paper";
                    newComputerChoice ();
                    computResult();
                });
                $('#scissors').click(function(){
                    userChoice = "scissors";
                    newComputerChoice ();
                    computResult();
                });
            }
        );

        function newComputerChoice ()
        {
            computerChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
            //take the random number from computerChoice above and assign it rock paper or scissors.
            if (computerChoice == 1)
                {
                    computerChoice = "rock";
                }
            else if (computerChoice == 2)
                {
                    computerChoice = "paper";
                }
            else 
                {
                    computerChoice = "scissors";
                }

        }
        function computResult()
        {
            var result; 
            if (userChoice == computerChoice){
                result="Tie!";
            } else if (userChoice == "rock" && computerChoice == "scissors"){
                result="You win!";
            } else if (userChoice == "paper" && computerChoice == "rock"){
                result="You win!";
            } else if (userChoice == "scissors" && computerChoice == "paper"){
                result="You win!";
            } else if (computerChoice == "rock" && userChoice == "scissors"){
                result="Sorry, you lose.";
            } else if (computerChoice == "paper" && userChoice == "rock"){
                result="Sorry, you lose.";
            } else if (computerChoice == "scissors" && userChoice == "paper"){
                result="Sorry, you lose.";
            }
            var table=document.getElementById("result");
            var row=table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
            var cell=row.insertCell(row.cells.length);
            var img=document.createElement("img");
            img.src=document.getElementById(computerChoice).src;
            $(cell).append(img);
            cell=row.insertCell(row.cells.length);
            img=document.createElement("img");
            img.src=document.getElementById(userChoice).src;
            $(cell).append(img);
            cell=row.insertCell(row.cells.length);
            cell.innerHTML=result;
        }



    </script>
    <table id="result">
        <tr>
            <td>Computer Choice</td>
            <td>Your Choice</td>
            <td>Result</td>
        </tr>   
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I like this, however, i would like to only display the computer choice below the 3 images the user can click on. Also how would i highlight an image that was clicked from the user?

Answer (score 0):

To display computer choice only, just remove the following statements.

```
        cell=row.insertCell(row.cells.length);
        img=document.createElement("img");
        img.src=document.getElementById(userChoice).src;
        $(cell).append(img);
        cell=row.insertCell(row.cells.length);
        cell.innerHTML=result;
```